# Calling Python Script From Perl

Tags: python, perl

I am trying to catch a python exit coode form inside perl.

My python code, py_test.py:

```
import sys
sys.exit(sys.argv[1])
```

My perl code, test.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
$res = system("python py_test.py ".$ARGV[0]);
print("\$res ==== $res \n >>>". $? ."\n");
```

I ran:

```
perl test.pl 4
```

The result was:

```
4
$res ==== 256
>>>256
```

I am using python 2.4.3 and perl 5.8.8 on 32bit RHEL 5.3.

Can someone help me understand what happened here, I can't seem to understand this behaviour, did I do something wrong? (I looked at this code for hours, I never encountered something this weird with system)

Comment: Was the result from `system` 1024?

Comment: Show your code .

Comment: See https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html to understand what is the `system` return value and how to use it. Some modules like `IPC::Run` may make your life easier than by calling a naked `system()`.

Comment: Or https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::System::Simple

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. We can't debug vague descriptions of code.

Comment: @melpomene Fixed. Is it OK now?

Comment: What happens if you run `python py_test.py 4; echo $?` in the shell?

Comment: Or [IPC::Run3](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my problem.
I entered to sys.exit argv[1], but at start python treats this as string.
After I changed it to sys.exit(int(argv[1])) everything worked fine.

That also explains why it printed the "4"...

Comment: So it turns out Perl had nothing to do with it. This is why preparing a minimal test case is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

from "perldoc perlvar"

```
$?      The status returned by the last pipe close, backtick (``) command,
        successful call to "wait()" or "waitpid()", or from the "system()"
        operator. This is just the 16-bit status word returned by the
        traditional Unix "wait()" system call (or else is made up to look
        like it). Thus, the exit value of the subprocess is really ("$? >>
        8"), and "$? & 127" gives which signal, if any, the process died
        from, and "$? & 128" reports whether there was a core dump.
```

It sounds like your python script may not be successfully exiting with the 4.

test.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys

sys.exit(4)
```

test.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;

system("./test.py");
print "\$? = $?\n"
die("Killed by signal ".( $? & 0x7F ) if $? & 0x7F;
die("Exited with error ".( $? >> 8 ) if $? >> 8;
print "Success\n";
```

Result:

```
~/test$ ./test.pl
$? = 1024
Exited with error 4
```